# Jquery Panel tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, panel

Ok so I am wanting to make a rpg system using php, mysql, and jquery. The idea is that there would be a tabbed content area that would have tabs for things like the town, the field, stats etc. Each tab would have a content area that is a call to a php system for that tab.

Here is the thing, is it possible to make a, what would be a window in a normal program, with jquery in which I can dynamically change the content. Let be give an example, the first tab that loads is stats, in here there would be more tabs/sections related to stats, with the first being character stats. But the first thing that I want to do is check to see if the user is logged in to the site, I know how to do that, that isnt the issue, the issue is when they are it checks to see if they have a character, if they dont it needs to load the character creation system, if they do it loads the stats tab.

Is there a way to say on they don't have a character show the creation system in the tab that would be stats, call the tab create, once they are down creating the character, load the stats in the same tab and rename it to stats.

Another words be able to setup a tabbed content system in which I can change the tabs via other php systems without having to make a whole new tabbed content system each time.

As you might think I am new to jquery. I have experience in php, though not tons, and mysql, html, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can refer below link for this.

[panel-tabs-content-using-jquery](http://chandreshmaheshwari.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/panel-tabs-content-using-jquery/)

Thanx.

Comment: That doesn't answer me really, I know how to make the tabs in the first place, I have that setup, the question is can I call the tabs content and change it based on the function I need.

Comment: i think you can do what u want by calling function onClick event using Jquery.Ajax..